# Best way to configure Kubernetes on local server

Tags: kubernetes

Through a stroke of luck I've been given an extremely powerful server in my office - I'd love to somehow set up a replica of our staging Kubernetes environment on it. Our staging Kube environment is 5 nodes running on AWS that each have different configurations. I can't find much in the way of best practice guides (probably because this is a very weird use case) for this configuration.

My gut feel is this:

- Install some kind of bare metal OS on the machine
- Set up multiple VMs on the machine each configured to mirror a node from staging
- Install the Kube master on one of the machines
- Enrol each of the other VMs as a node under kubernetes
- Run my deployments

Is there any better way for me to configure this or any potential issues I may hit/roadblocks if I follow this approach?

Comment: This is a bit broad to be answered exactly as it largely depends on your existing setup. Find out how the production and staging clusters were built and follow those same instructions. Ideally the setup is via a config management tool, a set of `kubeadm` commands or some config you throw at [kubespray](https://www.kubespray.io/), otherwise you're in for a ride.

Comment: What I can add is you can still use [AWS Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-2-virtual-machine.html) for the VM's.

Comment: Also each vm will be a [node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/). A [pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/) is a different concept for managing applications, i.e many pods can run on a node.

Comment: @Matt Sorry mate, I specifically meant node but my brain wrote pod. I want to basically have multiple nodes running on the same machine - I think the multi-VM solution is a good one - I've been using k8s for over a year and still keep making this mistake haha

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have it everything in one machine, I would also go for the multi-vm option. With Vagrant you could try to make the process simpler. This could help you:

https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-vagrant-coreos-cluster

After setting up the cluster you could adapt it to mimic the state of your staging cluster.

The only issue that comes to mind is that of overlay networking an external access. If you configure NAT networking you would have issues with external access and probably no issue with the network overlay. On the other side, I am not 100% certain how the overlay network would work in a bridged setting.